# Pulling with android maven plugin

Tags: maven, android

Здравствуйте, есть у меня магическая проьлема с пулом артефактов после билда с карты памяти телефона, после запуска интеграционных тестов. Вообщем дело такое. Есть у меня в поме вот такой конфиг:

```
 <pull>
   <source>/sdcard/test</source>
   <destination>${basedir}/target</destination>
</pull>
```

Я не хардкодил /mnt так как просто /sdcard означает то что оно будет ее искать, где бы она не была, но суть не в том. Если запускать это все на емуляторе или на любых девайсах от HTC, то артефакты пулятся без проблем. А вот на любом Samsung, то ли это S3, Note, Note2, Galaxy Nexus, Nexus S не пуляет, пишет, что нет такой папки на девайса, но как нет, если она есть. Вот ошибка

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.generation2:android-maven-plugin:3.2.1-SNAPSHOT:pull (pullResults) on project test: Cannot execute goal: /mnt/sdcard/test does not exist on device. -> [Help 1]
```

Но если сделать так:

```
adb pull /sdcard/test /$mypath
```

Все пуляется без каких либо проблем. Магия? Черное колдунство?
Начал дебажить, вот такой у меня стектрейс

```
 Cannot execute goal: /mnt/sdcard/test does not exist on device.
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:217)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:84)
 at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:59)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.singleThreadedBuild(LifecycleStarter.java:183)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:161)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:320)
at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:156)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:537)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:196)
at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:141)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:290)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:230)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:409)
at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:352)
 Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException: Cannot execute goal: /mnt/sdcard/OCIntegrationTestsResults does not exist on device.
at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.standalonemojos.PullMojo.getFileEntry(PullMojo.java:248)
at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.standalonemojos.PullMojo.access$100(PullMojo.java:52)
at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.standalonemojos.PullMojo$1.doWithDevice(PullMojo.java:130)
at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.AbstractAndroidMojo.doWithDevices(AbstractAndroidMojo.java:622)
at com.jayway.maven.plugins.android.standalonemojos.PullMojo.execute(PullMojo.java:121)
at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:101)
at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:209)
... 19 more
```

Как видно нет доступа к ней, но все права на нее и все что та м внутри l/rwx/rwx/rwx. Не знаю как побороть, надеюсь на Вашу помощь. Спасибо.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Если кому то интересно, полечилось в версии 3.5.3 обновили модуль роботы с NDK, и все пофиксилось.